# Throw a 404 error at /wp-admin/

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running the [Rename wp-login.php](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) plugin on my WordPress website. This plugin allows you to 'rename' `wp-login.php` and `/wp-admin/` so the visitor can't find the admin login.

However, when the visitor visits `/wp-admin/` he'll be seeing the *'You must log in to access the admin area'* error message.

I want to change this so the visitor sees a 404 page. The code for this error message is as follows:

```
if ( is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    wp_die( __( 'You must log in to access the admin area!', 'wp-login' ) );
}
```

I have tried changing it to

```
if ( is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    function generate_404() {
       global $wp_query;
       $wp_query->set_404();
    }
    add_action('wp','generate_404');
}
```

and I have also tried

```
if ( is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
}
```

But none of that did work. Please help me out.

Comment: Actually, displaying the message you pasted is more secure than showing a 404 error that would indicate that `wp-admin` is located elsewhere, while this is a "honeypot" that will make the hypothetical hacker that he's on the right page.

Comment: @AntoineB so I should leave it like it currently is?

Comment: If you don't HAVE TO have a 404, I'd say so indeed.

Comment: @AntoineB True, I think I'm gonna make an option for it. So I can choose to show a message or a 404 page. Do you mind helping me out to get the 404 code working? :)

Comment: @AntoineB Do you know a lot about PHP classes? I need some help with a few more things, maybe you can help me out!

Comment: I know barely anything related to Wordpress, but I might be able to help you with PHP classes, that said, you'd be better off submitting a new question if this one is not too related.

Comment: Hi @AntoineB, can you take a look at my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355224/issues-with-php-classes-and-wordpress)? It's appreciated!